# Android project - Define an EditText size

Tags: android, view, size, width, android-edittext

Hi guys I'm trying to set the width of an EditText.
My goal is to set the length of the EditText exactly 1/2 of the total screen.

I wrote this code:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
int width = rl.getWidth();
int half = width/2;

EditText userName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.userName);
userName.SET_SOMEHOW_THE_SIZE(half);
```

But i can't find a working method to set the width :(

Thanks 
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco,

`EditText` inherits `TextView`.  This means you can use the inherited [`setWidth()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setWidth%28int%29) method.

Comment: Thanks the problema was that the screen size returned was 0 so I used this function:
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

Answer (score 3):

Better done within the layouts, don't use code

the following creates an EditText that takes half screen, and a TextView that takes the other half, just learn to play with the layouts, they should let you get the result you expect

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: nevermind, just be sure to follow my suggestion when you're customizing your layouts in the future =)

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
userName.setWidth(half);
```